# Temprarly change $PATH only for the script run

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I hope that you can help me with the following problem: I want to implement a script that requires that $PATH variables has missing . value changes in it.

The point of the script is to find requested files and copy them to parent directory. I can do this using -execdir, but the problem is that . is defined in the $PATH.

Can you please tell me how can I provide a temporary replacement for the $PATH variable that can be valid only for the script execution.

Thanks

Comment: Change the PATH variable in your script.

Comment: @JNevill I can do this using export command... but will the change be active only for the execution of the script... or longer

Comment: Only for the script. The script is run in a child environment that adopts the parent environments values, but has no access to change them.

Answer (score 2):

The shell allows you to set environment variables of an executable by passing them to the invocation. Like this:

```
PATH="/foo/bar" program
```